# How to change the output type in ckeditor 5 from bbcode to html

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, bbcode

I downloaded ckeditor and used it without any changes in the project, but when sending to the backend, it displays bbcode instead of html tags.
This problem was easily solved in version 4, but I could not find a way for version 5

```html
# Hello

**This Is Test**

Example 2
```